# weird bug(?) with getValue returning "You are trying to edit a protected cell or object"

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

This is just...bizarre...

I'm running a function with a user that *does* have full *Edit* access to the Sheets in question.

This code:

```
function test() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('importDailyOrders');
  
  var column = sheet.getRange("A1:A");
  // Plain text
  column.setNumberFormat("@");
 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('orderSummary');
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
}
```

...gives me this error

> Exception: You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit. (line 11, file ...

But commenting out the `setNumberFormat` allows the function to run.

Note that the code works fine for the Sheet owner. This error only happens when running the script by a different user.

Is this a bug? If not...what's happening?

Answer (score 3):

Oh geez, the error message totally misled me. The problem was with the   `column.setNumberFormat("@");` on the *other* because *that* tab was protected.